# How to use gravatars in pinax?

Tags: python, django, pinax, gravatar

Pinax, no longer offers gravatars by default, and to make it even worse, the [django-gravatar project](http://code.google.com/p/django-gravatar/downloads/list) is gone.

So how to use gravatars in pinax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [the maintained fork](https://github.com/nvie/django-gravatar). But really it shouldn't be hard to make a template tag that returns a gravatar url for an email address anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use gravtr using Pip:
`pip install gravtr`

```
from gravtr import Gravtr
     gravtr = Gravtr("gfabricio@tests.com")
     gravtr.generate()
'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/1c0d59fd98fb89ba3a4f3ea950d31e1e'
```